# Save data in single byte Kana for japanese language

Tags: sql-server, database, double-byte, kana

I have a situation where I am storing bank name for Japanese culture for Japan.
So the problem is we found the Bank Name which should be kana is saving as Double bytes Kanji in Database.

The image below is being displayed as double byte

[image: The image below is being displayed as double byte]

This is how we save it in database.

[image]

So please let me know how can we save it in single byte kanji.

I don't have much knowledge on Double and Single byte Kanji or Kana,I have went through various article but could'nt get much information

This is how my table structure looks like
[image]

**Expected Result**s: Single kana should be saved to bank name

**Actual Results**: Double byte bank name is being saved

Comment: read : http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49254

Comment: There are 256 possible characters you can theoretically store in a single byte. How many Kanji are there? So, *"single byte kanji"*... what does that even mean? What's the point in not using Unicode?

Comment: @PrabhatG This wont work, please have a look at this https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3457130

Comment: @Tomalak well japanese character does store in double byte as well as single byte.It depends on half-width and full-width.and For the collation part may be , we have to change the collation.

Comment: No, half-width and full-width has to do with the *printing width* of Kana (not Kanji!). It has to do nothing at all with how many bytes you need to store the character. This is the Word "katakana" written in full-width Katakana: `カタカナ` and this is the same word in half-width Katakana. `ｶﾀｶﾅ`

Comment: @Tomalak so what do you suggest?

Comment: I can't suggest anything because I have no idea what your point is. All I can say is: Store the characters you need to store and don't bother how many bytes that takes.

Comment: @Tomalak Does changing the collation will work?As i am very confused as how to move forward.

Comment: The collation determines how characters are ordered and compared to each other. It does not have any influence on how many bytes a character needs. Can you explain what your problem really is, because I am pretty sure that single byte/double byte is not it.

Comment: @Tomalak Got your point, one last thing I would like to ask, how can we save any text in single byte, I guess we have to write that way, and we cannot convert it

Comment: When you ask me *"how can we save any text in single byte"* after all that I have written above, then you have **not** got my point, at all.